# R: Reading in an unconventional TSV structure

Tags: r

New to R.  I'm using a piece of software that exports data in a TSV format for each subject with some meta data at the top, and then with observations in columns rather than rows.

For example:

```
SOFTWARE: My Software
SLICE: Midventricular
SEGMENT: Midwall

Slice  Number   Frame 1   Frame 2   Frame 3 ...
    2      1        4.9       5.6       7.3     ...
    2      2        7.1       3.2       7.2     ...
    2      3        4.9       7.0       5.3     ...
    2      4        8.4       9.2       8.2     ...
    2      5        2.1       4.2       7.1     ...
    2      6        3.4       6.1       6.5     ...
```

Basically, I want to (a) discard the meta information and (b) read each column (starting with Frame 1) into a data frame as an observation.  I don't really care about preserving the headings that the software gives, as I can define that myself when I set up the dataframe.  I've looked through the documentation and some examples on `readLines`, `as.matrix`, and `read.table`, but am still at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at the `skip` parameter in `read.table`.  This allows you skip a specified number of lines in the file before it attempts to read in the actual table.

Comment: @PyNewb, You may also wish to set the `colClasses` argument to "NULL" in order to skip columns. For example, if you want to skip 'Slice' and 'Number', and keep the remaining three columns as `numeric`: `colClasses = c("NULL", "NULL", rep("numeric", 3)))`

Comment: @Henrik Good call - I guess I skipped the part where they wanted to skip columns as well.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I don't know how I missed that.  That got rid of the header information, and then I was able to transpose the data easily with (t).  Really appreciate it!

Comment: @PyNewb If it answered your question then please do the courteous action and add the checkmark.

Comment: @DWin: New to Stack Exchange as well--thanks for the heads up!

Comment: One other question for @Henrik--how could I chance your colClasses code to account for an arbitrary number of rows?  In my case it is different for every subject.

Comment: What do you mean?  colClasses has to do with the number of columns - not the number of rows.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for an arbitrary number of columns

Comment: There is a `fill` argument. You really should post a sample dataset that offers the features that are causing difficulties for a good answer.

Comment: @PyNewb, if your data file always start with two columns you wish to skip using `read.table`, followed by numeric columns only, then one possibility is to use `count.fields` on your data file, subtract 2, and then use this number in `colClasses = c("NULL", "NULL", rep("numeric", your-count.field-number-minus-two)))`. Or maybe just read all columns, and subset the data frame instead...